# Assigning variable from selectInput in Shiny - R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do an exercise in Shiny, where I select some variable from a menu. The options in the menu have the same name as variable in a dataset. I would then like to make some prediction between the variables which have been selected. 
My data set looks like:

```
head(MegaReport)
         DATE HOUR         STATION  FSP  NO2  NOX   O3  RSP  SO2
160873 1990-01-01    1 CENTRAL/WESTERN N.A. N.A. N.A. N.A. N.A. N.A.
160874 1990-01-01    2 CENTRAL/WESTERN N.A.   60   62 N.A. N.A.    3
160875 1990-01-01    3 CENTRAL/WESTERN N.A.   44   46 N.A. N.A.    5
160876 1990-01-01    4 CENTRAL/WESTERN N.A.   40   42 N.A. N.A.    4
160877 1990-01-01    5 CENTRAL/WESTERN N.A.   33   33 N.A. N.A.    6
160878 1990-01-01    6 CENTRAL/WESTERN N.A.   32   34 N.A. N.A.    4
```

The code that i built is:

```
 ## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
# demoing optgroup support in the `choices` argument
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("Pollutant", "Choose the first pollutant:",
                  list(`Nitrogen` = c("NO", "NO2"),
                       `Ozone` = "O3",
                       `Particulate` = c("RSP", "FSP", "IA"))
      ),

      selectInput("Pollutant2", "Choose the second pollutant:",
                  list(`Nitrogen` = c("NO2", "NO"),
                       `Ozone` = "O3",
                       `Particulate` = c("RSP", "FSP", "IA"))      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      sidebarPanel(
        textOutput("result"),
        textOutput("result2"),
        tableOutput("data")
      )
    )
  )),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$result <- renderText({
    paste("Active Pollutant 1", input$Pollutant)
  })
  output$result2 <- renderText({
    paste("Active Pollutant 2", input$Pollutant2)
  })
  output$data <- renderTable({
    MegaReport[, c(input$Pollutant, input$Pollutant2), drop = FALSE]
  }, rownames = TRUE)
})}
```

But when i run it, I cannot generate the new dataset that will select only the two columns from the initial dataset based on the 2 variables selected by the user.

Does anyone knows how to do please? what seem wrong to you ?

Comment: Can you check `class(MegaReport)`? Also, it would be helpful to copy a part of your data using `dput(head(MegaReport))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in not matching the column names with the `selectInput` for Nitrogen.  The `NO` should be `NOX` as in the `selectInput` or change the column names in `MegaReport`

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  # demoing optgroup support in the `choices` argument
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          
          selectInput("Pollutant", "Choose the first pollutant:",
                      list(`Nitrogen` = c("NOX", "NO2"), #change
                           `Ozone` = "O3",
                           `Particulate` = c("RSP", "FSP", "IA"))
          ),
          
          selectInput("Pollutant2", "Choose the second pollutant:",
                      list(`Nitrogen` = c("NO2", "NOX"), # change
                           `Ozone` = "O3",
                           `Particulate` = c("RSP", "FSP", "IA"))      )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          sidebarPanel(
            textOutput("result"),
            textOutput("result2"),
            tableOutput("data")
          )
        )
      )),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$result <- renderText({
        paste("Active Pollutant 1", input$Pollutant)
      })
      output$result2 <- renderText({
        paste("Active Pollutant 2", input$Pollutant2)
      })
      output$data <- renderTable({
       
        MegaReport[, c(input$Pollutant, input$Pollutant2), drop = FALSE]
      }, rownames = TRUE)
    })}
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
MegaReport <- structure(list(DATE = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1990-01-01", 
"1990-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1990-01-01"), HOUR = 1:6, STATION = c("CENTRAL/WESTERN", 
"CENTRAL/WESTERN", "CENTRAL/WESTERN", "CENTRAL/WESTERN", "CENTRAL/WESTERN", 
"CENTRAL/WESTERN"), FSP = c("N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A.", 
"N.A."), NO2 = c("N.A.", "60", "44", "40", "33", "32"), NOX = c("N.A.", 
"62", "46", "42", "33", "34"), O3 = c("N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A.", 
"N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A."), RSP = c("N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A.", "N.A.", 
"N.A.", "N.A."), SO2 = c("N.A.", "3", "5", "4", "6", "4")), .Names = c("DATE", 
"HOUR", "STATION", "FSP", "NO2", "NOX", "O3", "RSP", "SO2"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("160873", 
"160874", "160875", "160876", "160877", "160878"))
```